# Displaying CollectionView groups in different views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icollectionview

I was just curious if it was possible to bind 2 different views to the same collection. One view displaying the contents of one group (`PropertyGroupDescription`) and one view displaying the other.. the target of the property group is a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may bind your views to two different [CollectionViewSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) that use the same collection as their [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.source.aspx).

Comment: Say I use:
"var blah = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollection);"
and do searches based on ICommand input? Do you know if the new CollectionViewSource is based off the default or if it's an entirely new presentation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'd recommend to create different CollectionViewSources in XAML.

Comment: I was quick to reply anyway. I knew I had read it somewhere before, for anyone interested it's here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx under remarks